# Mysql Primary Key Search Preformance

Tags: mysql

Can someone explain which indexed search would be faster, listing from fastest, to slowest in a table with 1 million rows.?

> index:  hexadecimal
>
> index:  decimal
>
> index:  unicode chars   ∓ ∞

Comment: What does this have to do with the primary key? In any case, use whatever field type is most appropriate for the data, worry about the performance after there is a problem, not before.

Comment: I switched it from primary to index in the message. forgot to change the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of this is determined by the length of the key. This means:

> Alphanumeric keys longer then 4 bytes (~ 4 characters) will perform less then an integer (= 4 bytes)

So, integer / decimal keys will perform pretty good. Unicode would be the poorest from your examples.

The difference between a hexaDECIMAL and a decimal is nothing: as long as it still fits in 4 bytes. If you exceed that, it will degrade in performance.

Comment: so a decimal search with 15 digits 218340105584896 would be the fastest, compared to a case sensitive alphanumeric key of a0K4iL2Z, and a 4 character unicode value would be the slowest?  ∞∡∜∂

Comment: As far as I'm aware of, YES! However this is just a very tiny differencee: waiting for I/O will takes lots longer.

Answer (score 0):

I brlieve you will not find the performance difference in case of any of that types.

Because other factors (like disk IO speed) eat much more time, and it hides any differences in b-tree search with decimal vs string keys.